# Загрузка файла изображения из интернета

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем здравствуйте. Хочу получить асинхронно картинку из интернета, в winforms,это делалось сразу в одну строку. Ну а тут вот мучаюсь, подскажите как правильно  изменить мой метод,чтобы правильно загружалось фото. Вот код моего метода.Тут  Task bmim= image; возникает ошибка конвертации.

```
public Task<BitmapImage> GetFoto(string url)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    byte[] imageByte = wc.DownloadData(url);
    MemoryStream byteStream = new MemoryStream(imageByte);
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.BeginInit();
    image.StreamSource = byteStream;
    image.EndInit();
    Task<BitmapImage> bmim= image;
    return bmim;
}
```

Comment: `Task<BitmapImage> bmim= image` — почему вы считаете, что это должно работать?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Вот оно и не работает, а как мне получить правильный результат,чтобы вернуть картинку как результат выполнения Таска

Comment: Что значит "из для"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите получить картинку асинхронно, то и используйте асинхронный метод для загрузки:

```
public async Task<BitmapImage> GetFoto(string url)
{
    ...
    byte[] imageByte = await wc.DownloadDataAcync(url);
    ...
    return image;
}
```

<sub>Код не проверял</sub>

Comment: Точнее wc.DownloadDataTaskAsync

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так можно

```
private async void _ButtonLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage();
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //зададим ожидание ответа от сайта
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

                //                                         берем адрес из текстбокса
                using (var response = await client.GetAsync(_TextBoxAddress.Text))
                {
                    //убедимся, что сервер ответил успешно
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    result.BeginInit();
                    result.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                    result.StreamSource = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                    result.EndInit();
                }

            }

            //отображаем
            _Image.Source = result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Произошла ошибка во время загрузки изображения: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```